# Speed up NDSolve compared to Python (calls to LSODA)

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, performance-tuning, modeling, astronomy

I migrated a numerical [model code from Python](http://www.mpe.mpg.de/~simonbr/research_pypdr/)  to Mathematica and am surprised how much faster the Python version runs. Profiling of the Python version tells me that it is about 100 times faster (120 secs. vs. ~3 hrs).

I didn't spend overly much time to optimize the Mathematica version yet because 
one of the major bottleneck seems to be the numerical solution of a system of differential equations. The DEQs solve the chemical balance in the interstellar medium and I need to evolve the system from 0 to > 3e16 seconds (100 mio. years). Python uses the old scipy odeint solver that calls a Fortran LSODA solver. As far as I understand, `NDSolve` calls the same solver and I would expect similar solution times, but there seems to be a huge overhead. The Python profiler gives about 0.057 seconds per solution of the DEQs while Mathematica needs ~ 0.75 seconds supposedly calling the same numerical backend. So about 10 times faster.

If you are interested you can [download the full model code here](https://github.com/markusroellig/PDRica).

Some remarks: I am fine with using LSODA. The full production model computations are usually done in Fortran and LSODA is typical, stable solver. SO there is no need to come up with a clever reformulation of the problem and applying a different solution strategy. This needs to work for larger/smaller systems and different physical and chemical conditions.

My question is: What are possible reasons for the big difference in computation times and how could I reduce that in `NDSolve`?

Now to the code example:

```
eqns={(yy[1]')[t]==<<122>>+7.64714*10^-7 yy[25][t] yy[31][t]+3.3*10^-7
       yy[28][t] yy[31][t],(yy[2]')[t]==0. +<<35>>,(yy[3]')[t]==0. 
       +<<95>>+7.64714*10^-7 <<1>> yy[31][t],<<56>>,<<1>>,yy[30]
      [0]==0.,yy[31][0]==0.}
```

The full expression for eqns can be [downloaded from pastebin](https://pastebin.com/HDfirxqR). It is a system of 31 equations and initial conditions. (But the dimension of the problem is an adjustable parameter.)

I solve the system with

```
ysol = Quiet@NDSolveValue[eqns, Table[yy[i], {i, 31}], {t, 0, 3. 10^16}]
```

The Python codes uses: `odeint(self.f_chem,y0,t,args=([n_tot,T],),               rtol=1e-10,atol=1e-10*n_tot,mxstep=10000,full_output=True)`. I ignore any settings for absolute and relative errors or Accuracy and PrecisionGoals because they make no significant difference in computation times. I also looked a little under the hood of `NDSolve` ([documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html)) but that didn't seem to get rid of the factor 10. Anny help and comments appreciated!

FYI: Plotting the result looks like:

```
 logspace[min_, max_, steps_, f_: Log] := InverseFunction[f] /@ Range[f@min, f@max, (f@max - f@min)/(steps - 1)]

 ListLogLogPlot[
    Evaluate[Table[{x, ysol[[i]][x]}, {i, 31}, {x, logspace[1., 10^16, 50]}]], 
    PlotLegends -> {"H", "H+", "H2", "H2+", "H3+", "O", "O+", "OH+", "OH", "O2", "O2+", "H2O", "H2O+", "H3O+", "C", "C+", "CH", "CH+", "CH2", "CH2+", "CH3", "CH3+", "CH4", "CH4+", "CH5+", "CO", "CO+", "HCO+", "He", "He+", "e-"}, 
    PlotRange -> {{10^6, 10^16}, {10^-10, 10^4}}, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

Addressing some of the comments by Henrik Schumacher and Michael E2.

I fully agree to Henrik Schumacher about the difficulties of not to compare apples with oranges here. Also, the stiffness of the problem is problematic. But its origin is physics/chemistry and it can't be helped. Also, fine tuning the solution of the particular system of ODEs, that I gave is  not necessary helpful, because the model needs to solve many of those with ever changing numerical coefficients iteratively. Fine-tuning step-sizes etc. might speed-up this solution and slow-down another one later. Overall I trust LSODA to figure out a reasonable stepping.

I also tried to set up the ODE solver with the same parameters in both systems, which is not straight forward. Python uses: relative error tolerance `rtol=1e-10`, an absolute error tolerance `atol=1e-10*n_tot`, and a max number of steps `mxstep=10000`. `n_tot` is 1e4 in this concrete example, i.e. `atol=1e-6`. To the best  of my knowledge, this corresponds to the following call to `NDSolve`

```
ysol=NDSolveValue[eqns, Table[yy[i], {i, 31}], {t, 0, 3. 10^16}, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 6, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 10, 
  MaxSteps -> 10000]
```

I am somewhat unsure about the translation of relative and absolute errors though. The timing difference to `ysol2=NDSolveValue[eqns, Table[yy[i], {i, 31}], {t, 0, 3. 10^16}]` is not significant. The results are roughly the same with ysol having some difficulties at t=1e9-1e10 seconds. But the results at t=3e16 are about the same. Dashed lines in the figure are ysol2, soldi lines are ysol (explicitely set numerics).

[image]

So I would argue that the detailed numerical settings, important as they are, are not the main point here. LSODA/Mathematica apparently does a reasonable job to handle the stiff system in either case. Timing suggests that this is not the relevant factor in total computation time.

**TIMING**

Michael E2 points out that the presented examples takes ~0.04 seconds on V11.3. This is odd, but I can confirm this. So far I developed and tested the code on V11.2 because the C compiler detection was buggy until recently. Apparently something significant changed from 11.2 to 11.3?

Here some tests (all done with  `AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 10, MaxSteps -> 10000` on a fresh kernel) with the versions available to me:

> 11.3  ->   0.04s
>
> 11.2  ->   0.45s
>
> 11.1  ->   0.49s
>
> 10.4  ->   0.42s

The difference the previously cited 0.7s might be due to messy kernel state and memory and I would like to ignore them at the moment.

One obvious improvement is to use the latest version. However, the questions remains: What is the reason for the factor 10 for Versions < 11.3?

Another question given the attention of the commenting experts: Can we crank down the computation times in V11.3 even further?

Comment: `ysol = NDSolveValue[eqns, Table[yy[i], {i, 31}], {t, 0, 3. 10^16}, 
  MaxStepSize -> 3. 10^16/10000]` runs through in about `1.15` seconds on my machine. Of course, an error message pops up because you use floating point numbers with extreme scalings (`10^-245` for one of the  coefficients in the ode and `10^16` for the maximal time). No wonder that this will cause issues.

Comment: A first step could be to apply `Simplify` to `eqns`. That gets rid of at least the very worst scaling issues.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I agree, but that is not the point here. Without MaxStepSize option, NDSolveValue runs without complaints and returns a physically reasonable result and I am fine with that. Python solve the exact same problem and is ten times faster using the same numerical engine.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher As I mentioned in the post Simplify might help at this particular setup but again Mathematica shouldn't be ten times slower solving that particular problem.

Comment: You have to be careful not to compare apples with oranges. You have to set up the ode solver with the same parameters in both systems.

Comment: The stiffness behavior might appear only for certain time step configurations; when it occurs, it will probably lead to an immense reduction of time steps, causing longer runtime. I suspect that the error messures in the Python and Mathematica setting do not coincide.

Comment: Haven't looked into the code, but did you generate all the symbolic ODEs **explicitly** in `NDSolve`? This will lead to severe overhead because pre-processing of large symbolic system is time-consuming, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147387/1871) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156804/1871) for example.

Comment: Maybe I missed something but the pastebin & `NDSolveValue` code provided takes me about `0.04` sec. total (V11.3) and produces a similar plot of solutions.

Comment: @xzczd I am not sure whether I understand your question correctly, but I precompute the system of ODEs, populate eqns with it and feed eqns to `NDSolve`. I don't create the system within the call to `NDSolve` with the exception of the list of variables.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Same for me (v11.3).  Markus, could you also add the plotting code to your question?

Comment: I mean, for example, `sys1 = {y'[t] == y[t], y[0] == Range[2018]};` and `sys2 = Table[{y[i]'[t] == y[i][t], y[i][0] == i}, {i, 2018}];` is mathematically the same, but the latter is more time-consuming when one solves it with `NDSolve`, because it's a larger and more complicated expression: `ByteCount /@ {sys1, sys2}`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That is odd, but I can confirm the numbers. See my edits.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I agree to your comments on the difficulties to compare. See my edits. It turns out that the actual settings are not a deciding issue in terms of CPU time. The results look different though. That is why I chose the ´Automatic` settings.

Comment: @ChrisK See my edits.

Comment: @xzczd Ah I see. No, it is not yet vectorized. I have to think about how to set up the system in vector form.

Comment: I compared the task time on one machine in versions 11.01 and 11.3. Indeed, the time differs by almost an order of magnitude - 0.536312 and 0.0707357

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the difference is due to what happens with machine underflow.  As of V11.3, underflow goes to machine zero instead of to arbitrary-precision numbers (as it does in versions < 11.3).  See [(94996)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94996), [(169361)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/169361), [(174587)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/174587). Try [`SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/174474) in versions < 11.3. Let me know if it works, and I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*First question.*
I'm pretty sure that the difference is due to what happens with machine underflow. As of V11.3, underflow goes to machine zero instead of to arbitrary-precision numbers (as it does in versions < 11.3). See [(94996)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94996), [(169361)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/169361), [(174587)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/174587). Try [`SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174474/catching-machineunderflow-in-version-11-3) in versions < 11.3 to see if it will prevent the use of arbitrary-precision numbers. (This seems to work according to the comments below; I cannot check, so if this does not work please let me know.)  The extra time needed to compute with such numbers could account for the difference in timings observed in the OP.

*Second question.*
I get a slight improvement over the ~0.04 sec. on the OP's code in V11.3 by vectorizing and compiling the RHS of the ODE.  In theory, I believe this approach can be made to work in versions before 11.3.  To help vectorize the ODE system, I made a slight simplification, which at machine precision makes no difference in the result.  One will notice the replacement

```
9.999999999999999`*^-31 + yy[1][t] -> yy[1][t]
```

in the code below.  Since `yy[1]` starts at `10000.` and never gets below `6000.`, adding `~10^-30` to it makes no difference at machine precision.  This change turns the system into a polynomial system, which is easy to vectorize and more importantly eliminates a lot of unnecessary divisions.  Also in V11.3, several of the coefficients in `eqns` evaluate (or underflow) to `0.` because they are less than `$MinMachineNumber = 2.22507*10^-308` in magnitude.  I'm not sure what will happen in versions before 11.3 when the code is compiled.  *Mathematica* should complain, but whether it will be a fatal error, I'm not sure.  I think by default the `"CatchMachineUnderflow"` of [`RuntimeOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuntimeOptions.html)  is set to `False`, which means it should work.  One could also try `SetSystemOptions[]` mentioned above.  Let me know if it does not work.

```
vars = Table[yy[i], {i, 31}];       (* yy[i] variables *)
dsol = First@Solve[eqns[[;; 31]], D[Through[vars[t]], t]];   (* derivatives *)
ics = Through[vars[0]] /. First@Solve[eqns[[32 ;;]], Through[vars[0]]];
cas = Normal@ CoefficientArrays[    (* coefficients of the quadratic system *)
  D[Through[vars[t]], t] /. dsol /. 9.999999999999999`*^-31 + yy[1][t] -> yy[1][t],
  Through[vars[t]]];
With[{P = cas[[1]], Q = cas[[2]], R = cas[[3]]},
 rhs = Compile[{{yy, _Real, 1}},
   P + (Q + R.yy).yy,
   RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}
   ]
 ]

ysol = NDSolveValue[
    {yy'[t] == rhs[yy[t]],
     yy[0] == ics},
    yy, {t, 0, 3. 10^16}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.028963, Null}  *)

ListLogLogPlot[ysol, Joined -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{10^6, 10^16}, {10^-10, 10^4}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: In _v9.0.1_, the timing reduces from about `0.78` to about `0.058` by setting `"CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False` option on my laptop. What's surprising is, without the option, Compile will spit out  the `Compile::cplist` warning; even after setting this option, the timing is about `0.14` i.e. the compiled version is slower! Behavior in _v11.2_ is similar: Before setting `"CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False`, uncompiled timing is about `0.69` and compiling fails after `Compile::cplist`; after `"CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False`, uncompiled timing is about `0.07` and compiled timing is about `0.08`.

Comment: I find a similar reduction in runtime by about a factor 10. Tested in 10.4, 11.1, and 11.2.

Comment: Regarding the second part of your answer: The vectorization is nice. Using `ics = eqns[[32 ;; -1]][[All, 2]]`  because it wasn't defined above I get the same result, however on my machine it runs ~ 50% slower compared to the original NDSolve run. Compiling with `"CatchMachineUnderflow" -> True` gave many errors and solution took 13 seconds. Can you explain why `ListLogLogPlot` can diggest the `InterpolationFunction`?

Comment: @MarkusRoellig Yep,I  forgot to include `ics`. Thanks. I used `Solve` and `vars` to ensure consistent ordering and to avoid the assumption that the second part of the equation was the IC. (You generate the systems and can make such assumptions, since you know and control their form.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Good point about the ordering. I am wondering why on my machine the unvectorized version runs faster.

Comment: @MarkusRoellig My guess is that it is because the coefficient arrays of the system are fairly sparse, and using them in the vectorized version entails many more multiplications (mostly by `0.`).  The efficiency of `Dot` either does or does not make up the difference.  There may be other differences in the versions of Mma.

Comment: @MarkusRoellig As for `ListLogLogPlot`, it seems to be a feature of the `ListPlot` family. See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134223/4999. `ListPlot[if]` is equivalent to `ListPlot[Transpose@{Flatten@if["Grid"], if["ValuesOnGrid"]}]`.  (For `"Grid"` etc., see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28341/4999.)