# How do computational resources required for NDSolve scale with integration time?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, performance-tuning, memory, crash

## In a nutshell

I have a large system of ODE. When I integrate the system from `x = 0` to `x = dx`, `NDSolve` returns the result happily, it takes about a minute, and `MaxMemoryUsed` tells me that about `100MB` was used to perform the computation. Because I have `8GB` RAM, I ask `NDSolve` to integrate the system from `x = 0` to `x = 2 * dx`, and it just crashes! I would expect memory required for `NDSolve` to increase linearly with integration time, am I wrong?

## Minimal Working Example

### Background

I have an extremely large first-order ODE system (59582 equations) of the form $y'(x) = f[y(x)]$, where $y(x)$ is an array of reals with `Dimensions` `{2, 31, 31, 31}`. Well, despite its size, compiled version of $f$ seems to compute the *rhs* pretty good, so I decided to give `NDSolve` a try. Because `NDSolve` evaluates the sytem symbolically, I create a `CompiledFunction` for $f$ and wrap it into another expression to protect it from symbolical evaluation and pass some extra data to the `CompiledFunction`:

```
ClearAll[$rhs, rhs];
$rhs = Compile[
   {
    {d1, _Integer},
    {d2, _Integer},
    {d3, _Integer},
    {state, _Real, 4}
   },
   Table[
    -(i + j + k + l)*state[[i, j, k, l]],
    {i, 1, 2},
    {j, 1, d1},
    {k, 1, d2},
    {l, 1, d3}
   ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
];
rhs[{d1_, d2_, d3_}][y_ /; ArrayQ[y, 4, MachineNumberQ]] := $rhs[d1, d2, d3, y];
```

The actual *rhs* is, of course, different from the one given above. I have chosen this one as an example which should not introduce any numerical problems (a linear system with negative real eigenvalues, what can be easier?).

All the rest is straightforward:

Here is the code for `NDSolve`:

```
ClearAll[solve];
solve[rhs_, y0_, xmax_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := NDSolve[
   {
    y'[x] == rhs[y[x]],
    y[0] == y0
   },
   y,
  {x, 0, xmax},
  FilterRules[{opts}, Options[NDSolve]]
];
```

Here is the code for the initial value:

```
BlockRandom[
 dims = {31, 31, 31};
 init = RandomReal[1, Prepend[dims, 2]];
 init = init/Sqrt[Total[init^2, Infinity]];,
 RandomSeeding -> 3
]
```

And here is the value of integration time which leads to the crash on my system

```
dx = 0.7;
```

I believe that this value depends on a system MMA is running on. By the way, mine is

```
$Version
(*"11.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)"*)
```

### The Problem

While `x < dx`, `NDSolve` works normally, and the memory it consumes increases linearly with the integration time:

```
mems = MaxMemoryUsed[
   solve[
     rhs[dims],
     init,
     #
   ]
] & /@ Range[0., dx, dx/10]
(*6385992, 52857744, 64484696, 71772376, 62706016, 66520768, 70335840, 80827824, 82735200, 89411304, 96087344*)
```

So that it takes about 100 MB to perform the computations for `xmax = dx`. Therefore, I wouldn't expect any problems for `xmax = 2 * dx`, but `NDSolve` just crashes the kernel for this value of `xmax`! Is it a bug, or do resources required by `NDSolve` increase faster then linearly?

Comment: Why do you use a standard solver to solve such a large number of first-order equations? Use the explicit Euler as the basis.  According to my observations, NDSolve can not solve such problems in general. It can break even on a hundred equations.

Comment: If the solution begins growing very rapidly, `NDSolve` will use progressively smaller time steps to maintain accuracy.  So, memory requirements easily can grow much faster than linearly, depending on the equations..

Comment: Just a side note, you can add `RuntimeOptions -> EvaluateSymbolically -> False`, or simply modify the definition to `Compile[……]//Last` given you've compiled to C, to avoid symbolic calculation.

Comment: In general, do not use NDSolve in this task. NDSolve is a black box. You never know how it will behave on such large problems with the number of equations $10^4-10^5$. Write your own numerical solution program.

Comment: @AlexTrounev, it is exactly the viewpoint I am fighting against. I really believe that a usual physicist, who is not a professional mathematician, will achieve much better results by understanding deeply how to use professional tools like Mathematica properly rather then wasting time on childish c++ programs. But thank you very much! Changing Method to an explicit one (Runge Kutta with any order) solved the problem. Now I ***have*** managed to make Mathematica solve a system of 60 thousand ODE for me smoothly in less then a minute :) Should you write an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Congratulations, but you do not know what you will get next time, what a surprise it will be. Every program has its limitations. And it's good if you know these limitations in the case of NDSolve.

Comment: @AlexTrounev, the point is that I do not claim that Mathematica can solve any problem. What I do claim is that all problems that cannot be solved by Mathematica *must* be **so** complex that they also cannot be solved by simple c++ programs which one might expect form an average physicist.

Comment: You can write the code on  the Wolfram Language not using C ++.

Comment: @AlexTrounev, If you are interested in the discussion, then we can proceed to the chat not to flood the comments. I am afraid that I have already violated some SE rule about that.

Comment: Write the answer to your question as you solved the problem. But not in the comments, but edit your question.

Comment: I do not agree that NDSolve should not be able to solve such large problems.  But I do agree that for such problems, you should not blindly use automatically selected methods. As Alex says, I would try to control the method directly and make sure that the step size isn't made unreasonably small. Here's how to control methods: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveOverview.html

Comment: Actually, such big problems would be the perfect use case for a high-level solver like `NDSolve`: the bulk of the computation time should be spent on calculating the RHS anyway. That part (which is usually simple) can be programmed in C if needed. That is what is effectively being done here (with `Compile`). The complicated part is implementing the solver method, and that's exactly where it makes sense to rely on an existing implementation. If you get serious about this and decide to go all-C++, you'd likely still end up using a library that handles the method ... so why not NDSolve then?

Comment: Perhaps this is also an issue: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/181165/4999

Comment: @MichaelE2 I tried that, doesn't seem to be related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A single `Method -> ExplicitRungeKutta` causes `ndstf` warning at about `t == 0.52` for `xmax == 2 dx`, but works well for `xmax == dx` on your sample. This phenomenon leads me to the following solution:

`MaxStepSize -> 0.01` resolves the problem, not quite sure about the reason though.

```
test = solve[rhs[dims], init, 2 dx, MaxStepSize -> 0.01]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {4.577509, Null} *)
MaxMemoryUsed[]/1024^2. MB
(* 223.226 MB*)
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. The maximal coefficient in the solution's exponent is `2 + 31*3 = 95`, which corresponds to characteristic dumping time `0.01`, so I would take ten time smaller then that. `NDSolve` still solves the system without a crash then, but takes more then 1GB RAM. So, I suppose, @Szabolcs is right and the reason why `NDSolve` crashes the Kernel is uncontrolled decrease in step size. Don't have time to edit my question now, will add all my conclusions sometime.