# Which Method does NDSolve use when solving a pde?

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

In this example

```
F = NDSolveValue[{Derivative[2, 0][f][x, y] == y^2*f[x, y],f[1, y] == 1, Derivative[1,0][f][1, y] == 1}, f, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

`NDSolve` evaluates to the correct solution, which can be confirmed by `DSolve`. I would like to know **which numerical method was used**.

I tried

```
F["Methods"]
(*{"Coordinates", "DerivativeOrder", "Domain", "ElementMesh", \
"Evaluate", "GetPolynomial", "Grid", "InterpolationMethod", \
"InterpolationOrder", "MethodInformation", "Methods", \
"OutputDimensions", "Periodicity", "PlottableQ", "Properties", \
"QuantityUnits", "Unpack", "ValuesOnGrid"}*)
```

Unfortunately `F["MethodInformation"]` doesn't evaluate.

Because `F["ElementMesh"]` gives `None`, I assume it's not a FEM-solver. I also tried `Trace` without success.

How can I get further information concerning "MethodInformation" used by `NDSolve ?`

Comment: In version 13.0 for Linux, with  `F["MethodInformation"]`, I get the error `MethodInformation called with 0 arguments; 1 argument is expected.`, so it seems that, at least in that version, your syntax is wrong.

Comment: @mattiav27 Thanks, same result in v12.2. All other options work, don't know how to find the correct syntax

Comment: trying this `command := 
  NDSolveValue[{Derivative[2, 0][f][x, y] == y^2*f[x, y], 
    f[1, y] == 1, Derivative[1, 0][f][1, y] == 1}, 
   f, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];
Select[Flatten[
  Trace[command, TraceInternal -> True]], ! 
   FreeQ[#, Method | NDSolve`MethodData] &]`  says `NDSolve Newton` at the end. before it said `NDSolve LSODA`

Comment: see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145/how-to-find-out-which-method-mathematica-selected

Comment: see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183102/details-of-ndsolve-calling-lsoda for LSODA

Comment: Note that "MethodMonitor"  suggested by user21 in the above post, no longer seems to work. It is still mentioned though here  https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDesign.html#1710185749   may be user21 could suggest better method to use these days.

Comment: Notice that checking `F` won't help much here, because `F` is an `InterpolatingFunction[…]` which isn't necessarily generated by `NDSolve`, and info of `NDSolve` is just not there. (Of course, you can check `ElementMesh` to determine if `FiniteElement` method is used. )

Comment: @Nasser Thanks for your comments. Need some time to understand outpu of `Trace`